# pymongo db already exists with different case already have

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo

Here is my code  :

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pprint import pprint
from collections import OrderedDict
import operator
client = MongoClient()
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client['searchPo']

db.video.create_index([("'video_id", 1),("unique", 1), ("dropDups" , 1)])
```

and i get this error :

```
 db already exists with different case already have: [searchPo] trying to create [searchpo]
```

And i don't understand why 
the name of my database is searchPo and there s no other database

thanks and regards

Answer (score 2):

[The manual says](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Database-Name-Case-Sensitivity), "database names cannot differ only by the case of the characters." You have a database already created named "searchpo", and you are trying to create an index on the collection "video" in the database named "searchPo" with a capital "P". Normally, MongoDB creates a database automatically when you create an index on a collection in the database, but here, since there's already a "searchpo" database with a lowercase "p", it refuses.

Replace this line:

```
db = client['searchPo']
```

with this:

```
db = client['searchpo']
```